# how to disable shipping option in paypal buy now button ?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

i want to charge a one time fee from the customers of my website so i am using **Paypal buy now button** but the problem is customer have to enter shipping details as well whereas in my case there is not product to ship so how to disable this option?

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to set 'no_shipping' to '1'.
E.g. `<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">`
See also https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

Comment: Great! Ensure you mark this answer as being helpful as well please; this improves the quality of StackOverflow and rewards those contributing answers.

Answer (score 0):

As per [these instructions](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/webhosting/sitebuilder2/paypal/paypal-20.html) , under the "Shipping Address" header, when you generate your button code in PayPal you can choose "Don't prompt for address".